# Jquery the toggleSlide,function doesnt work why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to slide the info but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
<div Class="article">
    <div id="ebook1">Ebook1</div>
    <div id="infoOfEbook1">
        Download The Ebook1 From Here.
    </div>      
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ebook1").click(function(){
            $("#infoOfEbook1").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/7xmZE/

Comment: What's your console say?

Answer (score 7):

You don't put your code inside the script tag with the src.  Change it to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#ebook1").click(function(){
         $("#infoOfEbook1").slideToggle("slow");
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @XxYo0nixX would you mind marking this answer as correct?